Even/Odd with reference to the interval (domain)
As the definition goes, a function $f(x)$ is even if $f(-x)=f(x)$ and it is odd if $f(-x)=-f(x)$, in which the domain is not paid enough attention to.
For example, $f(x)=x^2$ is even for any symmetric interval centered at the origin, while it is not even in an internal like $[0, 2\pi]$.
The question is why almost all of the textbooks do not pay much attention to the interval/domain of definition.

If you say a function satisfies an equation such as $f(-x) = f(x)$ without specifying for what $x$ this is supposed to be true, the default assumption would be that the left side is defined whenever the right side is defined, i.e. in this case the domain of the function should be symmetric about $0$.

If you change the domain you change the function.

@RobertIsrael, thank you for the comment.

I agree that domains of definition merit more attention than they are getting in some textbooks.
The definition of even and odd functions only makes sense on domains where the operation $-x$ is well-defined. A commenter suggested that this could be reasonably done on a real interval symmetric about the origin (the full set of reals being a particular case), but of course you could also take the complex numbers or symmetric subsets of them, or any subset of a group that is symmetric about the neutral element.
The tangent function from trigonometry is an example of an odd function with a nontrivial domain.
